# Starting PostgreSQL server failed after modification of postgresql.conf using the sudo command

Tags: postgresql, configuration-files, root

I wanted to change the "shared_buffers" parameter in my postgresql.conf file.

The problem is that I used the sudo command and it gave the ownership to the root.

```
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root root  13661 Mar 14 15:36 postgresql.conf
```

Then I used the following command to get back the ownership to postmaster :

```
sudo chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
```

So I tried the command :

```
postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/data
```

I was badly surprised to still get the following error message

```
postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf": Permission denied
```

below id the result of the "ls" command in the directory realted to postgreSQL :

```
sudo ls -l /var/lib/pgsql/data/
total 208
drwx------  19 postgres postgres   4096 Mar 13 17:23 base
drwx------   2 postgres postgres   4096 Mar 14 14:30 global
drwx------   2 postgres postgres   4096 Mar  5 14:26 pg_clog
-rw-------   1 postgres postgres   3365 Mar  1  2006 pg_hba.conf
-rw-------   1 postgres postgres   3182 Mar  1  2006 pg_hba.conf.old
-rw-------   1 postgres postgres   1460 Feb 24  2006 pg_ident.conf
drwx------   2 postgres postgres 139264 Mar 14 00:00 pg_log
drwx------   4 postgres postgres   4096 Feb 24  2006 pg_multixact
drwx------   2 postgres postgres   4096 Mar 14 10:42 pg_subtrans
drwx------   2 postgres postgres   4096 Feb 24  2006 pg_tblspc
drwx------   2 postgres postgres   4096 Feb 24  2006 pg_twophase
-rw-------   1 postgres postgres      4 Feb 24  2006 PG_VERSION
drwx------   3 postgres postgres   4096 Mar 14 14:30 pg_xlog
-rw-rw-rw-   1 postgres postgres  13661 Mar 14 15:36 postgresql.conf
-rw-------   1 postgres postgres     49 Jan  2 17:15 postmaster.opts
```

If someone have an idea of could be the way to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Fred

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check how is SELinux running:

```
# sestatus
```

If it is in enforcing mode check the log:

```
# less /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

If you find SELinux blocking then temporarily disable SELinux just to confirm it is the culprit:

```
# setenforce 0
```

Now try to start the server. If it works then reenable SELinux:

```
# setenforce 1
```

Search for how to restore SELinux settings for that file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I got "bash: sestatus: command not found". Do you have another suggestion in mind ? Cause I am starting to be crazy after one afternoon browsing the web without no clue.

Comment: @Fred Given the file path I thought you were using a RedHat derived OS. What is the OS?

Comment: FYI : I am under RedHat Enterprise Linux WS Release 4

Comment: @Fred did you try to start the server as root or as postgres? To start the server do (as root) `# service postgresql start`

Comment: no unfortunatelly I also got `bash: setenforce: command not found`

Comment: Actually I can't log as root but when I tried the command with my account [ffleche@myLinux] with our without sudo I got the same not found command. I am starting to feel stupid.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error right after a fresh install.
First the default file mode bits of all files in `/var/lib/pgsql/data/` are set to `600` and yours `postgresql.conf` has `666`. This isn't the problem in the case but it's good to keep the things as they are.
I am not familiar with RedHat distro but from the comments it seems that this is not a problem with SELinux.
On my Fedora 20 running:

```
$ systemctl start postgresql.service
```

seems to run the server.

And if you want to execute some commands in PosgtreSQL for first time - like creating your own user for ex. you may find this question helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/110154/whats-the-default-superuser-username-password-for-postgres-after-a-new-install